# ubuntu installation replacing of windows 7 without partitioning

Tags: software-center

I have already 5 drives in my PC. I want to install ubuntu replacing of win 7 on drive c without touching other drives. But how?

Answer (score 0):

when you are installing ubuntu it will ask you to install alongside windows or something else. click on something else and at the partition manager just select the drive that you want to install ubuntu on and it should just overwrite your windows 7 installation without partitioning